# Print with custom header, other details and footer in Blazor Server application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, blazor-server-side

Print to PDf Blazor Server form layout, which is built using devexpress.

In my blazor server app, I have some instrument details and piechart built using devexpress controls. In my requirement I want to print this form including piechart, to pdf with print privew along with header and footer customized.

I have tried window.print but here I get side menu options and other layouts in page which is not required for my requirement.

I have also tried getting the div tag to print using window.open and window.print. However I get styling issues and also there is new window opened.

Please let me know for any other options that suffice my requirement.

Thanks in advance!